# Are there any online services for software documentation with full UML-Support?

Tags: uml, documentation-viewer

I'm looking for a service to bring the opensource-software documentation of my current project online.

Therefor I have the following requirements:

- must handle user authentication (for sure everyone shall be able to see the documentation, but not everyone can edit it)
- must be hosted from an external service
- Version-history of pages, when edited
- Full support of UML-Diagrams (we have many UML-Diagrams which must be editable easily when something has changed)
- Data-backup or at least fully supported Export
- common requirements like, support for extensive formatting and easy upload of external pictures and other media.

On my search so far I had a watch on a wiki-system and read the docs. but both don't fulfill my needs as much as hoped.

Can anyone give me an advice or hint what service might be useful for my needing?